# Magento1: add extra 2 field to customer registration for fronted ,admin , and database

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, registration, field

I followed several tutorials like   https://marketplace.magento.com/  followed the step but no luck for me. how to **add 2 extra field** in **customer or user registration** for frontend ,admin and database . any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example you need to insert the required field(telephone) into the table. I will always encourage to accomplish this using a custom module, although it is time taking, it is a standard and cleanest way.

1. Create a standard module with minimal required files.
2. Create InstallData.php in the following path NameSpace\ModuleName\Setup

```
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Setup;

  use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {

      /**
       * CustomerSetupFactory
       * @var CustomerSetupFactory
       */
      protected $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
       * $attributeSetFactory
       * @var AttributeSetFactory
       */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

      /**
       * initiate object
       * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
       * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
          AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      )
      {
          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
          $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      }

      /**
       * install data method
       * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
       * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {

          /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
          $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
          $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

          /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          /**
           * customer registration form default field mobile number
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Telephone',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();


      }
  }
```

3. Add the field to the frontend by copying module-`customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml` and add

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?= __('Telephone') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**FOR MAGENTO 1.x PLEASE REFER TO THE LINK BELOW**

[How to create additional fields for Customer Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426242/how-to-create-new-fields-for-customer)

Comment: thanks to reply but my question was for magento1.9. can you please do same for Magento 1

Comment: Okay i'll try....

Comment: @irshad I'm updating my Question with a reference link, if u'll find it helpfull please accept is as answer.

Comment: thanks it's helpful

Comment: @irshad Please accept it...

Comment: please follow this link for   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292131/magento2-3-2-override-vendor-magento-module-inventory-source-deduction-api-mode